# The active users count dont match on execution through 2 containers in Kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, jmeter

We are running jmx through Tauras using 2 containers in Kubernetes.
We are seeing only 50 users in results instead of 100(50*2 containers).
Can anyone please through some light if we are missing something here.
We get two jtl and checking them individual or combined the total users are same 50 only. Is it related to same Thread name being generated and logged in jtl file or something else.

### Here is the yml details:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: joba
  namespace: AAA
data:
  protocol: "https"
  serverUrl: “testurl”
  users: "50”
  duration: "1m"
  nodeName: "Nodename"
  ---
apiVersion: /v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: perftest
  namespace: dev
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - args: ["split -l ${users} --numeric-suffixes Test.csv Test-; /bin/bash ./Shellscripttoread_assignvariables.sh;"]
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
        env:
        - name: JobNumber
          value: "00"
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: job-multi
        image: imagepath
        name: ubuntu-00
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: “8000Mi"
            cpu: "2880m"
      - args: ["split -l ${users} --numeric-suffixes Test.csv Test-; /bin/bash ./Shellscripttoread_assignvariables.sh;"]
        command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
        env:
        - name: JobNumber
          value: "01”
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: job-multi
        image: imagepath
        name: ubuntu-01
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: “8000Mi"
            cpu: "2880m"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML is very nice but it doesn't tell anything about how do you launch JMeter or what these shell scripts you invoke are doing.

If you just kick off 2 separate JMeter instances by means of k8s - JMeter will look at the number of active threads from the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and given the Sampler/Transaction names are the same JMeter "thinks" that the tests were executed on one engine.

The workaround is to add i.e. [machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function to sampler/transaction labels, this way JMeter will distinguish the results coming from different instances and you will see real number of active threads.

The solution would be running your JMeter test in [Distributed Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) so master will run in one pod, slaves in their own pods and the master will be responsible for transferring .jmx script to the slaves and collecting results from them

Comment: Thank you Dmitri.